# Missing 64-Bit support while Uploading to AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, arm64, nsuinteger

I was trying to validate and upload my app to app store.But it ended up with a error as [Error Missing 64-bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1zL6.png)

I made changes by adding arm64 in valid architectures and standard architectures(armv7,arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Build Active Architecture only - No

After adding this there was a error coming as " ('NSInteger' (aka 'long')) does not match type of instance variable 'stage' ('int') ".

I changed the int as "NSUinteger" and error as link command error.

Is my app doesn't support 64-bit??.

Answer (score 0):

`int` --> `NSInteger`.

PS: `int` == `signed int` != `unsigned int`